# How big is too big in flutter shared_preferences?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

I am currently working on the cache handling of the app. Shared_Preferences documentation states that bigger information should be stored somewhere else, but all I work with is pretty much Arrays that can only be up to 800-900 elements long, containing simple integers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is basically no limit specified for storing the data in SharedPreferences
Still, its an advice to store big data in Database, because you can access Objects from it, and shared preferences can only store primitive data types(String, int, float, etc)

Answer (score 2):

Both Android's `SharedPreferences` and iOS `NSUserDefaults` are basically just proxies over XML files which are stored inside application's internal storage area, and do not have storage limits.

If your design is compliant with using shared preferences instead of, for instance, database, then I suppose that you are good to go.